# How to import lib folder within Modules

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7

I had a GAE app which contains three Modules and a lib folder. When I tried to import the 3rd party library from the lib folder. GAE pops a ImportError.

I could get it to work by symlinking ./lib to ./Module_1/lib and ./Module_2/lib and also creating a appengine_config.py in each of the modules. But doing this seemed really dirty.
Is there a cleaner way to import app_root/lib from module_1 and module_2?

This seemed to be promising(https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Includes), but don't know what to put inside include.yaml.

```
-- App Root/
    -- Module_1/
       module_1.yaml 
       module_1.py

    -- Module_2/
       module_2.yaml
       module_2.py

    -- lib/ 
       -- cloudstorage/
          ..
       -- 3rd_library_1/
          ..
          ..
       -- 3rd_library_2/
          ..
          ..

    appengine_config.py
    main.py (default module)
    app.yaml(default module)
    queue.yaml
    dispatch.yaml
```

In module_1.py or module_2.py, when I do

```
    import cloudstorage as gcs
```

It complains

```
    ImportError: No module named cloudstorage
```

However, when it's being imported within main.py, it works fine.

In the appengine_config.py:

```
import os
import sys

# Add ./lib to sys path
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'lib'))
```

Also tried to print sys.path from main.py:

```
sys.path in main.py :
[ 
  '/base/data/home/apps/s~my-app/2.381942946570489905', 
  '/base/data/home/apps/s~my-app/2.381942946570489905/lib', 
  ...
  ...
 ]
```

sys.path in module_1.py:

```
 [
  '/base/data/home/apps/s~my-app/module_1:2.381942955973772449',      
  '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python27.zip', 
   ...
   ...
  ]
```

Comment: Only folder containing *.yaml file will be uploaded on GAE, so your `lib` folder should be inside of your module. Make a symlink.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Credit goes to Google Cloud Platform Tech Solutions Representative Adam:

> Modules documentations may not be explicitly
>   stated, but the folder 'Module1', 'Module2' as well as the default
>   module actually run inside separate Python virtual environments on
>   separate instances and need to be self contained. They cannot 'see'
>   any directories above them which exist on the local filesystem, and
>   'default.py' can't see anything in each of the module directories. The
>   whole folder tree isn't copied to each module instance.

He suggested that instead of making symlinks, just copy ./lib to each of the modules.

I do not like the idea very much.

Firstly, these modules share some base class, duplicating them is really an anti-pattern.

Secondly, copying the lib folders everywhere corrupts unit tests as nose will try to run all unit tests it can run, also because it's a pain to explicitly exclude the directories.

At the end of the day, I wrote a makefile to help deployment / testing easier...

```
# Create simlinks before deployment.
deploy: mksimlnks
    appcfg.py --oauth2 update $(CURDIR)/app.yaml
    appcfg.py --oauth2 update $(CURDIR)/MODULE_1/module_1.yaml
    appcfg.py --oauth2 update $(CURDIR)/MODULE_2/module_2.yaml
    appcfg.py --oauth2 update_queues $(CURDIR)

mksimlnks:
    ln -s $(CURDIR)/lib $(CURDIR)/MODULE_1/lib
    ln -s $(CURDIR)/lib $(CURDIR)/MODULE_2/lib

# Need to remove symlinks before unittest
# or unit test will explode.
test: rmsimlnks
    nosetests --exclude-dir=lib --with-gae -w $(CURDIR) --with-coverage --cover-html

# Remove all symlinks
rmsimlnks:
    rm -rf $(shell find * -type l)

# remove symlinks and other stuff
clean: rmsimlnks
    rm -f $(shell find * -name *.pyc)
    rm -f $(shell find * -name .DS_Store)
    rm -f .coverage
    rm -rf $(CURDIR)/cover
```