# PyCharm PYTHONPATH different in Python Console vs running the GAE development server?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pycharm

While trying to figure out how to properly import the Google Identity Toolkit into my GAE project I observed that when running the project in PyCharm (v. 4.5.2 pro) the PYTHONPATH is **NOT** the same as in PyCharm's Python Console.

For example in the Console I properly find the oauth2client library from the GAE SDK (v. 1.9.23):

```
/usr/bin/python2.7 -u /home/usr_local/pycharm-4.5.2/helpers/pydev/pydevconsole.py 43085 43754
Python 2.7.8 (default, Sep 30 2014, 15:34:38) [GCC]
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 2.2.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.
PyDev console: using IPython 2.2.0

import sys; print('Python %s on %s' % (sys.version, sys.platform))
sys.path.extend(['/home/user/src/myapp', '/usr/local/google_appengine', '/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/antlr3', '/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/apiclient', '/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/endpoints-1.0', '/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/yaml-3.10', '/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/markupsafe-0.15', '/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/django-1.3', '/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/requests', '/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/fancy_urllib', '/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/webob_0_9', '/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/graphy', '/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/distutils', '/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/concurrent', '/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/cacerts', '/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/six', '/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/pyasn1', '/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/setuptools-0.6c11', '/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/jinja2-2.6', '/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/portpicker', '/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/django-0.96', '/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/django-1.2', '/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/PyAMF-0.6.1', '/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/sqlcmd', '/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/oauth2client', '/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/uritemplate', '/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/httplib2', '/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/protorpc-1.0', '/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/python-gflags', '/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/rsa', '/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/grizzled', '/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/django-1.5', '/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/ipaddr', '/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/django-1.4', '/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/argparse', '/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/google-api-python-client', '/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/mox', '/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/cherrypy', '/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/prettytable', '/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.3', '/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/oauth2', '/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/pyasn1_modules', '/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2', '/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/websocket', '/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/yaml', '/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/docker', '/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/simplejson', '/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.1', '/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/deprecated_enum'])

Python 2.7.8 (default, Sep 30 2014, 15:34:38) [GCC] on linux2
In[2]: from oauth2client import crypt
In[3]: crypt
Out[3]: <module 'oauth2client.crypt' from '/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/oauth2client/oauth2client/crypt.py'>
In[4]:
```

But when running the project I get:

```
  File "/home/user/src/myapp/main/identitytoolkit/gitkitclient.py", line 47, in <module>
    from oauth2client import crypt
ImportStringError: import_string() failed for 'gitkit.GitKitHandler'. Possible reasons are:

- missing __init__.py in a package;
- package or module path not included in sys.path;
- duplicated package or module name taking precedence in sys.path;
- missing module, class, function or variable;

Original exception:

ImportError: No module named oauth2client
```

I'm also dumping the sys.path before the exception (real paths are displayed, `/usr/local/google_appengine` is a symlink to `/home/usr_local/google_appengine_1.9.23`):

```
ERROR    2015-06-30 18:59:46,199 gitkit.py:13] ['/home/user/src/myapp/main', '/home/usr_local/google_appengine_1.9.23', '/home/usr_local/google_appengine_1.9.23', '/usr/lib64/python2.7', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/home/usr_local/google_appengine_1.9.23/lib/webapp2-2.5.2', '/home/usr_local/google_appengine_1.9.23/lib/jinja2-2.6', '/home/usr_local/google_appengine_1.9.23/lib/pycrypto-2.6', '/home/usr_local/google_appengine_1.9.23/lib/markupsafe-0.15', '/home/usr_local/google_appengine_1.9.23/lib/setuptools-0.6c11', '/home/usr_local/google_appengine_1.9.23/lib/protorpc-1.0', '/home/usr_local/google_appengine_1.9.23/lib/webob-1.1.1', '/home/usr_local/google_appengine_1.9.23/lib/yaml-3.10']
```

Is there a way to configure PyCharm to apply the same PYTHONPATH from the Console (which is IMHO correct) to the development server execution?

Alternatively - how does PyCharm determine/configure the development server execution path? (I don't mind even configuring the correct path manually if needed).

Donno if relevant, but I've upgraded the PyCharm and GAE SDK versions several times while working on this project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the GAE development server adjusts its own execution path depending on the SDK installation **and the executed app code itself**.

The failures in my case were caused by incorrect 3rd party lib vendoring in a multi-modules app. I documented my fix here: [Is Google Identity Toolkit (v3) compatible with GAE/python sandbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31082344/is-google-identity-toolkit-v3-compatible-with-gae-python-sandbox)